# How we can check our App is running in real device or bluestack?

Tags: android

I Just want to check my app is running in bluestack or in real device.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: go to ddms and look into the process into the device listed there

Comment: @N5. I guess he wants to check it programmatically whether user is using his app in real device or in bluestack!

Comment: @Anuj please keep a practice of checking existing questions over Stackoverflow!